# Correct method to solve Polymorhism classes in Java?

Tags: java, class, polymorphism

This is a homework question I can't figure out.

Find the output of:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object o = new A();
        A a2 = new B();
        B b = new B();
        a2.report(b);
    }

public class A {
    public void report(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Object");
    }

    public void report(A a) {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public void report(A a) {
        System.out.println("A again");
    }

    public void report(B b) {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

When I tried to work the solution, I first tried to figure out what would happen at the compile time. I thought that a2 would use class A and report b which is not defined in class A and therefore would default to report object. This would give the solution of "Object". However, this is not correct. I can't figure out how this method would report "A" when the function is should be calling report(B b).

Comment: Remember, a `B` *is* an `A`.

Comment: `a2` doesn't know anything about  `report(B b)` try `((B)a2).report(b);`